# Confusion with Calendar object

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar

I have a date time which comes in milliseconds. eg:1394504624657L and using following code I'm converting it to Calender object.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.setTimeInMillis(millis);
```

Above it can be UTC or GMT.

```
1394504624657L represents Tuesday, March 11, 2014 2:23:44 AM GMT
```

Then I'm returning `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)` which returning 2 which is the expected value. But when I remove the zone and use the default zone it returns 7. What should be the correct way to use this functionality ?

Also when using FastDateFormat I'm getting date value as "2014-3-11 2:23:44" and its format as "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss". And using following code I'm creating the Calender function again.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
FastDateFormat userSpecificFormat;
userSpecificFormat = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date userSpecifiedDate = userSpecificFormat.parse("2014-3-11 2:23:44");
cal.setTime(userSpecifiedDate);
```

Then I'm returning `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)` which returning 2 which is the expected value. But if I set the zone like (TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")) it returns 8. As you can see they are two different behavior. I'm really confused of this. Any help to clarify this behavior?

Comment: I know that it's not an answer, but i recommend you joda-time or DateUtils by Apache Commons !:)

Comment: You should explain where this `FastDateFormat` class is coming from as it is not bundled with Java. The Google knows of at least two, one on Tomcat and one in Apache utils.

Comment: FastDateFormat from apache commons lang package. Its functionality is same as SimpleDateFormat class

Comment: @user3919392 What is the default time zone of your JVM and host OS?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a mismatch between the parsing format and the input string. You have two characters for the hour in the pattern, which means at least two digits. But your input data has a single digit for hour.

Ditto for month.

Comment: I provided two digits as you have mentioned but still having the same issue.. :(